# How To Associate a Selected Value to an Uploaded IFormFile

Tags: c#, jquery, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc, iformfile

In ASP.Net Core and JQuery, I am trying to associate the selected value from a Select List to the IFormFile that is being uploaded. The select list options are a list of categories and the file being uploaded needs to belong to one. There could be several IFormFiles being submitted with the form submission but each file has to be categorized with the id of the selected category (not a multi-select but several single files).

I am using a JQuery .each() to get the IFormFile values and the categoryId but the value of the categoryId is null when it hits the C# controller method.

```
--JQuery--
$(':file').each(function (index, field) {
   var file = field.files[0];
   formData.append('files', file);
   var attachmentTypeId = $(this).parent().parent().find('option:selected').val();
   formData.append('attachments.Attachment.AttachmentTypeId', attachmentTypeId);
});
```

```
--C# ViewModel--
public Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
public List<Attachment> Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
public IFormFile File { get; set; }
public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
```

```
--C# Attachment Class--
public int AttachmentTypeId { get; set; }
public string FileName { get; set; }
public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
```

```
--C# Controller Method--
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ViewModel viewModel)
{
   if (viewModel.Files.Count > 0 || viewModel.File != null)
   {
      foreach (var file in viewModel.Files)
      {
         Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
         {
            FileName = viewModel.File.FileName,
            AttachmentTypeId = viewModel.Attachment.AttachmentTypeId
         };

         using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
         {
            viewModel.File.CopyTo(ms);
            var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
            string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
            attachment.FileContent = fileBytes;
         }

         path = $"Attachments/Create";
         content = new JsonContent(attachment);
         await _client.PostData(path, content);
      }
   }

   return Ok();
}
```

I am trying to get the selected value from the Select List selected Option into the JQuery FormData Object (this works) and pass that through an AJAX call to the C# Controller Method (everything works except for the selected id).

Comment: there is an `Attachment` and `Attachments` Property on the ViewModel. Which one is to be populated?

Comment: Attachments. Attachment is for returning back to the view.

Comment: @bcedergren 1. "but the value of the categoryId is null" Do you mean the `AttachmentTypeId` is null? But the `AttachmentTypeId ` has a type of `int`. 2. Is there a minimal demo that reproduces ?